# Pyramid Framework - Help with creating a view function

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

I have the following code for the view:

```
def pages_view(request):
    path = request.path.split('/')[1]
    dbsession = DBSession()
    page = dbsession.query(PagesTable).from_statement(
    'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE path=:page_path').params(page_path=path).first()
    pages_dir = os.getcwd() + '/myblog/templates/pages/'
    if page:
        if path == '':
            return render_to_response('myblog:templates/pages/home.mak',
            {'page':page}, request=request)
        elif os.path.isfile(pages_dir + path + '.mak'):
            return render_to_response('myblog:templates/pages/%s.mak'%path,
            {'page':page}, request=request)
        else:
            return render_to_response('myblog:templates/pages/index.mak',
            {'page':page}, request=request)
    raise NotFound()
```

Basically, it checks if a page exists in the table. If it does it
renders a template according to the path name, or if there is no such
template it just renders a default template.

The next part I want to do is create a seperate view function for my
'blog' page, with some logic for this page.

I've tried the following example, but it throws an undefined error
when when I load the page:

```
@view_config(renderer='myblog:templates/pages/my-blog.mak')
def blog_view(request):
    one = 'Hello World'
    return {'one':one}
```

I do apologise for such basic questions. Any insight given will be
greatly appreciated.

Here is the traceback:

```
URL: http://127.0.0.1:6543/my-blog/
    File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/WebError-0.10.3-py2.6.egg/weberror/evalexception.py', line 431 in respond
  app_iter = self.application(environ, detect_start_response)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/repoze.tm2-1.0b1-py2.6.egg/repoze/tm/__init__.py', line 23 in __call__
  result = self.application(environ, save_status_and_headers)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.0-py2.6.egg/pyramid/router.py', line 158 in __call__
  response = view_callable(context, request)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.0-py2.6.egg/pyramid/config.py', line 2916 in _requestonly_view
  response = view(request)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/MyBlog/myblog/views.py', line 25 in pages_view
  {'page':page}, request=request)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.0-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py', line 111 in render_to_response
  return helper.render_to_response(value, None, request=request)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.0-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py', line 322 in render_to_response
  result = self.render(value, system_values, request=request)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.0-py2.6.egg/pyramid/renderers.py', line 318 in render
  result = renderer(value, system_values)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid-1.0-py2.6.egg/pyramid/mako_templating.py', line 131 in __call__
  result = template.render_unicode(**system)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.3.6-py2.6.egg/mako/template.py', line 292 in render_unicode
  as_unicode=True)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.3.6-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py', line 575 in _render
  **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.3.6-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py', line 607 in _render_context
  _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.3.6-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py', line 633 in _exec_template
  callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
File 'myblog_templates_pages____base_mak', line 27 in render_body
File 'myblog_templates_pages_my_blog_mak', line 34 in render_body
File '/Users/Awais/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Mako-0.3.6-py2.6.egg/mako/runtime.py', line 181 in __str__
  raise NameError("Undefined")
NameError: Undefined
```

Comment: What is your question? And how is the code from the first view function related to the second one? Also, you say it raises an undefined error, can you provide a stack trace? What is undefined?

Comment: Well the first part of my system was to design something that would render pages depending on their path and if they were in the database or not. The second step is to use one of the pages, and create some logic for that page, in this case a blog. When I pass arguements in the second view function and then call those in the template, I get an undefined error. I am assuming maybe this has got to do something with the first view function I have created, I am already rendering that template, and then I am kind of rendering it again in the second view function. I  hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please add the traceback of the error you get.

Comment: Hi, I have added the traceback of the error above.

Comment: The error appears to be happening during the rendering of your mako template. Take a look at the template, and post if you can't figure it out. I'm still not sure if there is a question for the first part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have been better off following through on this question rather than starting the other one. Based on information here and in the [comment you provided in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289680/pyramid-framework-can-you-call-two-seperate-view-functions-to-the-same-template/5290023#5290023), the following is taking place:

View:

```
def view1(request)
    args1 = 'a string'
    return render_to_response('page.mak',{'args1':args1}, request=request)

def view2(request)
    args2 = 'a string 2'
    return render_to_response('page.mak',{'args2':args2}, request=request)
```

You have the following in your 'page.mak' template file...

`${args2}`

When view1 is called, render_to_response tries to render the page.mak template. The dictionary `{'args1'=args1}` is used as context. When mako sees `${args2}`, it looks up `args2` in the context dictionary. The context dictionary constructed in view1 does not have `args2` in the context dictionary, so it will cause an error. Rendering this same page in view2 works fine, because view2 is correctly passing the expected value with the key `args2`.

So, the error you're getting is because of trying to render a variable in your template that you never placed into the template context dictionary.

Comment: Thank you Mark. This is very helpful, and clears up things. So my next question would be how do I resolve this? I do apologise for asking such primative questions.

Comment: @user614954 I'll be honest, you actually have a few questions here, and you're changing the code on us, so it's difficult to keep track of what the current state of the code and problem is.

Comment: Yeh, sorry about that I was trying to simplify things, but I guess I have made it a little confusing. Refering to the new code I have just put, how do I call the view2 view function. view1 is being called with the config.add_route... and then how do I do make variables in view2 available in view1? Perhaps using global variables outside the functions? I hope I am making sense.

Comment: you should change {'args1/2'=args1/2}  into {'args1/2':args1/2} :)

Answer (score 0):

It look's like you have configuration issues in your routing system, try 
to change the action to this, if it works maybe its a permission issue, 
could post the stack trace that the error raise?

```
def blog_view(request):
    one = 'Hello World'

    return render_to_response('myblog:templates/pages/my-blog.mak',
        {'one':one}, request=request)
```

Comment: Hi, I did try that too but it returned the same error. I have added the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the first part of the code, resolves the error.

Perhaps because render_to_response for my-blog.mak is occuring twice?

In the first part of the code you have

```
return render_to_response('myblog:templates/pages/%s.mak'%path,
```

Which renders my-blog.mak if it exists,

The second time I do:

```
def blog_view(request):
variable = 'hello world'
return render_to_respomse('myblog:templates/pages/my-blog.mak', {'variable':variable}, request=request)
```

The thing is I need something first renders the templates if they exist or not and are in the database table.

The second part is creating some seperate logic for that particular template.

Comment: You should add details to your original question, not as a possible answer. Just add a "Edit:" in bold before what you add to let people know you added details.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mark Hildreth said in the comments of your original question, the error seems to be happening during the rendering of your template. You probably try to do something with a variable that does not exist/is not set in your view function.

In your first example, you always set a `page` variable, maybe that's the one missing.