# Pyramid Framework - Can you call two seperate view functions to the same template

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pylons, pyramid

I was playing around with the pyramid framework, and I was wondering if it is possible to call two view functions to the same template:

so for example:

```
def view1(request)
    args1 = 'a string'
    return render_to_response('page.mak',{'args1'=args1}, request=request)

def view2(request)
    args2 = 'a string 2'
    return render_to_response('page.mak',{'args2'=args2}, request=request)
```

So, note both are using the **page.mak** template.

Answer (score 6):

> {'args1'=args1}

is not valid Python.

> {'args1':args1}

is though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. Why do you suspect this would be a problem? Have you tried it and hit some error?

Comment: Well yes, when I call the argument ${args2} in the template file, I get a NameError("undefined")

Comment: One more thing to add: view1 is being invoked with config.add_route('new','/page'/, view='myproject.views.view1') view2 is not being called. Maybe this is why I get the error? If that is the case what are methods for calling view2, I don't need to do add_route again?

Comment: You'll need to specify the same set of template variables for both renders of the template. They don't have to have the same values, however. I often use this technique to render a form page for creating a new object or editing an existing object. Same template, different values.

Comment: I confess I did not actually read your code, just your question. The answer to your question is "yes". But your code has two problems, already pointed out by Chris McDonough and dcrosta: it contains syntactically incorrect Python, and you are using two different  variable names ('args1', 'args2') when calling the template. Because it is just one template, and it presumably refers to those variables, then the variable names should be the same in both rendering calls.